# h5py extend dataset without knowing row index

Tags: python, numpy, h5py

## EDIT to show more accurately my situation

```
import h5py  # necessary for storing data
import numpy as np

dat = np.random.random([3, 2])

# create 'test.hdf5' if not exist, otherwise open
with h5py.File('test.? Shdf5', 'a') as f:
    # create group or get ref to existing group
    group = f.require_group('test_group')

    # create dataset or get ref to existing dataset
    dataset = group.require_dataset('test_set', shape=(0, dat.shape[1]),
                                      maxshape=(None, dat.shape[1]),
                                      dtype=float, chunks=True)
    dataset_shape = dataset.shape  # get shape of current dataset
    dataset_new_length = dataset_shape[0] + dat.shape[0]  # new row length
    dataset.resize((dataset_new_length, dat.shape[1]))  # increase row length dataset
    dataset[dataset_shape[0]:dataset_new_length] = dat  # add new data to dataset
```

## Problem

The first time 
I run this script, it works without problems. The 2nd time however `shape=(0, dat.shape[1])` does not match anymore, because it became `shape=(3, dat.shape[1])`. The whole point of `require_dataset()` is that you don't have to make a `try: except:` construction, however because of the required `shape=()`, it does not work with a `maxshape=(None, dat.shape[1])`.

Also, `shape=(None, dat.shape[1])` is not allowed.

## Question

Is there a solution using `require_dataset()` that **does not use a `try: except:`** like this *(if you replace `dataset = group.require_dataset()` with this piece of code, the script runs without problems)*?:

```
try:
    dataset = group.create_dataset('test_set', shape=(0, dat.shape[1]),
                                   maxshape=(None, dat.shape[1]),
                                   dtype=float, chunks=True)
except:
    dataset = group['test_set']
```

## Better solution would be

A command where I don't need to know the size would be even better, as something like this:

```
dataset = dataset.extend(data)
```

Comment: Can't you get the size with `dataset.shape` or something similar?

Comment: Currently not on the right PC to test, but how would you imagine using `dataset.shape`. I could indeed use `.shape`, then resize, then subtract the new `.shape` to get the count of empty rows. However this would involve 4 lines. I was hoping there was an easier way?

Comment: Wrap it in a function and no one will know how much work you did!  Just don't call it `append`.  The `np.append` is badly named and often misused.

Comment: I updated the code with a runnable example of the problem of my situation.

Comment: I inquired about this problem on the Google Groups of h5py (`group.require_dataset()` not flexible enough): https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/h5py/BHQj4YkFKk4

Comment: `np.source(f.require_dataset)` show that it tries to match on `name`, `shape`, and `dtype`.